# Gridpanel rowediting plugin returned Id

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am using [gridpanel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) with [rowediting](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing) plugin. I have an "Add new record" button in the toolbar of my grid. When I press this button new empty row being created in the grid. So I fill the newly created row with all the neccessary data and then press "Update" button of rowediting plugin to submit. So after submitting I got new record in the grid without an Id (because the Id is being calclulated on server). I was trying to send the Id of newly created instance back with response, but it looks like rowediting plugin doesn't pick it up and doesn't associate it with newly created row entry. Any ideas?

P.S. Imagine that right after adding a new record we decided to remove it right away. Since the record has no Id it will be impossible to do that without reloading the store, because we have nothing (i.e. no Id) to send to server.

Comment: do you think you could put your code in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the new id for the record in the success response callback, and then call the setId method for the new record